# Katalon studio - Only local connections are allowed - terminal issue

Tags: testing, automated-tests, functional-testing, katalon-studio

I am trying to run my project on the terminal as I heard it is a huge advantage but every time I try to do it got this issue 'Only local connections are allowed and then every test is failed, how can I fix it ?

[image]Grab the screenshot of this error.

```
2018-12-11 10:35:10.383 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/Contrahent/Buttons belowe contrahents card avatar/Cnt - Removing contrahent FAILED.
Reason:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Config.txt (No such file or directory)
    at Cnt - Removing contrahent.run(Cnt - Removing contrahent:23)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:321)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:312)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:291)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:283)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:222)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:129)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:112)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:149)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestSuite1544520887488.run(TempTestSuite1544520887488.groovy:36)

2018-12-11 10:35:10.384 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - END Test Cases/Contrahent/Buttons belowe contrahents card avatar/Cnt - Removing contrahent
2018-12-11 10:35:10.389 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - --------------------
2018-12-11 10:35:10.389 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - START Test Cases/Contrahent/Buttons belowe contrahents card avatar/Cnt - Removing contrahent
2018-12-11 10:35:10.406 DEBUG testcase.Cnt - Removing contrahent       - 1: openBrowser("")
2018-12-11 10:35:10.406 WARN  c.k.k.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory    - A browser is already opened. Closing browser and opening a new one
UPDATE_RECORD Test Cases/Contrahent/Buttons belowe contrahents card avatar/Cnt - Removing contrahent
UPDATE_RECORD Test Cases/Contrahent/Buttons belowe contrahents card avatar/Cnt - Removing contrahent
2018-12-11 10:35:10.551 INFO  c.k.k.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory    - Starting 'Chrome' driver
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052) on port 38374
Only local connections are allowed.

Here is an issue
```

Comment: Please don't only show error outputs in screenshots but paste the text here directly.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is all I can see from your screenshot. I don't see the "only the local connections are allowed". Please, copy and paste relevant parts of the log.

Comment: Could you show the script where the error occured?

Answer (score 0):

Your tests are not failing because of the "only the local connections are allowed" part. They are failing because of `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: What does it mean though?
I had copied the directory what was generated through from KATALON STUDIO

Comment: It is just a warning. Saying that ChromeDriver will accept connections from the local machine.

Comment: The point is the test doesn't run at all. When I have let's say test which should remove a contractor from a database, on the terminal it doesn't remove. When I run it on KATALON STUDIO it does remove.

Comment: Make sure the file in question is present on the terminal.